# How to use jsonpath length() function if list of elements is nameless?

Tags: apache-nifi, jsonpath

So usualy  I use this function like this `$.some_element.length()`

But now my json has no name for the list of elements it has this structure:

```
[
{somedata1},
{somedata2}
]
```

How can I found out length of this list? I've tried `$.length()` and `$.*.length()` nothing works.

Comment: `$.length()` should work

Comment: @daggett Hello! It adds attribute but value of this attribute is an empty string somehow

Comment: could you try it here? https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @daggett weirdly it worked here, doesn't work in ni-fi though) 
Thank you very much anyways!

Comment: maybe you have an issue in json file format...